# Getting a boost::shared_ptr for this

Tags: c++, boost

I am making extensive use of `boost:shared_ptr` in my code. In fact, most of the objects that are allocated on the heap are held by a `shared_ptr`. Unfortunately this means that I can't pass `this` into any function that takes a `shared_ptr`. Consider this code:

```
void bar(boost::shared_ptr<Foo> pFoo)
{
    ...
}

void Foo::someFunction()
{
    bar(this);
}
```

There are two problems here.  First, this won't compile because the T* constructor for `shared_ptr` is explicit. Second, if I force it to build with `bar(boost::shared_ptr<Foo>(this))` I will have created a second shared pointer to my object that will eventually lead to a double-delete.

This brings me to my question: Is there any standard pattern for getting a copy of the existing shared pointer you know exists from inside a method on one of those objects?  Is using intrusive reference counting my only option here?

Comment: "_Is using intrusive reference counting my only option here?_" What's wrong with this option?

Comment: Maybe nothing. Depends on your circumstances. It does make your objects bigger and may not work in places where you don't have control over the classes you're keeping smartpointers to.

Comment: enabe_shared_from_this is now in `std::` . Have a look at my answer.

Answer (score 102, accepted):

You can derive from [enable_shared_from_this](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/libs/smart_ptr/enable_shared_from_this.html) and then you can use "shared_from_this()" instead of "this" to spawn a shared pointer to your own self object.

Example in the link:

```
#include <boost/enable_shared_from_this.hpp>

class Y: public boost::enable_shared_from_this<Y>
{
public:

    shared_ptr<Y> f()
    {
        return shared_from_this();
    }
}

int main()
{
    shared_ptr<Y> p(new Y);
    shared_ptr<Y> q = p->f();
    assert(p == q);
    assert(!(p < q || q < p)); // p and q must share ownership
}
```

It's a good idea when spawning threads from a member function to boost::bind to a shared_from_this() instead of this.  It will ensure that the object is not released.

Comment: f() is like ".Copy()" and it is also a shallow copy.

Answer (score 19):

Just use a raw pointer for your function parameter instead of the shared_ptr.  The purpose of a smart pointer is to control the lifetime of the object, but the object lifetime is already guaranteed by C++ scoping rules: it will exist for at least as long as the end of your function.  That is, the calling code can't possibly delete the object before your function returns; thus the safety of a "dumb" pointer is guaranteed, as long as you don't try to delete the object inside your function.

The only time you need to pass a shared_ptr into a function is when you want to pass ownership of the object to the function, or want the function to make a copy of the pointer.

Comment: Agreed.  Many times you can use foo( const Object* object_ptr ){} foo( obj.get() ); where obj is a boost::shared_ptr< Object >.  

Do search on the web for Herb Sutter, is a an other and article writer who has some great information about this and similar issues.

Comment: It's little beside the point, but... If you can use pointer, then (most likely) you can use reference, which is better IMO.

Comment: @denis-bu, except when a `NULL` pointer is a possibility. But you make a good point.

Comment: Obviously 12 years late to this, but I don't understand this answer. The type of the argument to bar is different from a raw pointer. Without the "explicit" keyword that would make passing "this" fail to compile, wouldn't the compiler try to construct the shared_ptr from the raw pointer, creating the reference count block in the process, set the reference count to 1, then on exit from bar, decrement the reference count to 0 and try to delete "this"?

Comment: @FosterBoondoggle my suggestion was to change the parameter type of `bar` to a raw pointer.

Answer (score 14):

boost has a solution for this use case, check [enable_shared_from_this](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/libs/smart_ptr/enable_shared_from_this.html)

Answer (score 9):

Are you really making more shared copies of pFoo inside bar? If you aren't doing anything crazy inside, just do this:

```
void bar(Foo &foo)
{
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 5):

With C++11 `shared_ptr` and `enable_shared_from_this` is now in the standard library. The latter is, as the name suggests, for this case exactly.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this

Example bases on that in the links above:

```
struct Good: std::enable_shared_from_this<Good>{
    std::shared_ptr<Good> getptr() {
        return shared_from_this();
    }
};
```

use:

```
std::shared_ptr<Good> gp1(new Good);
std::shared_ptr<Good> gp2 = gp1->getptr();
std::cout << "gp2.use_count() = " << gp2.use_count() << '\n';
```

Answer (score 3):

The function accepting a pointer wants to do one of two behaviors:

- **Own the object** being passed in, and delete it when it goes out of scope.  In this case, you can just accept X* and immediately wrap a scoped_ptr around that object (in the function body).  This will work to accept "this" or, in general, any heap-allocated object.
- **Share a pointer** (don't own it) to the object being passed in.  In this case you do *not* want to use a scoped_ptr at all, since you don't want to delete the object at the end of your function.  In this case, what you theoretically want is a shared_ptr (I've seen it called a linked_ptr elsewhere).  The boost library has [a version of shared_ptr](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm), and this is also recommended in Scott Meyers' Effective C++ book (item 18 in the 3rd edition).

**Edit:** Oops I slightly misread the question, and I now see this answer is not exactly addressing the question.  I'll leave it up anyway, in case this might be helpful for anyone working on similar code.