# Why shared_pointer does not allow definition like ptr = new Object;

Tags: c++, shared-ptr

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why shared_ptr has an explicit constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/304093/why-shared-ptr-has-an-explicit-constructor)

It baffles me why `std::shared_ptr<int> p1(new int(10));` is OK while, while `std::shared_ptr<int> p2 = new int(10);` fails? I *think* the two should be constructed in the same way.