# Why is unique_ptr<T>(T*) explicit?

Tags: c++, pointers, c++11, type-conversion, unique-ptr

The following functions do not compile:

```
std::unique_ptr<int> foo()
{
    int* answer = new int(42);
    return answer;
}

std::unique_ptr<int> bar()
{
    return new int(42);
}
```

I find this a bit inconvenient. What was the rationale for making `std::unique_ptr<T>(T*)` explicit?

Comment: For the same reasons [`shared_ptr` is explicit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/304093/why-shared-ptr-has-an-explicit-constructor).

Comment: Can you really use a `unique_ptr` in the return type like that? It doesn't make sense to me, the whole point is that you can't copy it.

Comment: @cha0site: it's a temporary, so it's moved, not copied.

Comment: @MooingDuck : Even if it wasn't a temporary, local objects are implicitly treated as xvalues in return statements anyway.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You don't want a managed pointer to grab ownership of a raw pointer implicitly, as that could end up in undefined behavior. Consider a function `void f( int * );` and a call `int * p = new int(5); f(p); delete p;`. Now imagine that someone refactors `f` to take a managed pointer (of any type) and that implicit conversions were allowed: `void f( std::unique_ptr<int> p );` if the implicit conversion is allowed, your code will compile but cause undefined behavior.

In the same way consider that the pointer might not be even dynamically allocated: `int x = 5; f( &x );`...

Acquisition of ownership is a important enough operation that it is better having it explicit: the programmer (and not the compiler) knows whether the resource should be managed through a smart pointer or not.

Comment: +1, esp for "Acquisition of ownership is a important enough operation that it is better having it explicit."

Comment: "_Acquisition of ownership is a important enough operation that it is better having it explicit_" Good point.

Answer (score 20):

**Short answer:**

The *explicit* constructor makes it difficult to write dangerous code. In other words, *implicit* constructor helps you to write dangerous code more easily.

**Long answer:**

If the constructor is *implicit* , then you could write such code *easily*:

```
void f(std::unique_ptr<int> param)
{
     //code

} //param will be destructed here, i.e when it goes out of scope
  //the pointer which it manages will be destructed as well.
```

Now see the *dangerous* part:

```
int *ptr = new int;

f(ptr); 
//note that calling f is allowed if it is allowed:
//std::unique_ptr<int> test = new int;
//it is as if ptr is assigned to the parameter:
//std::unique_ptr<int> test = ptr;

//DANGER
*ptr = 10; //undefined behavior because ptr has been deleted by the unique_ptr!
```

Please read the comments. It explains each part of the code snippet above.

When calling `f()` with a raw pointer, the programmer may not realize that the parameter type of `f()` is `std::unique_ptr` which will take ownership of the pointer and will `delete` it when it goes out of scope. Programmer on the other hand may *use* it, and `delete` it without even realizing that it has already been deleted! This all happens because of *implicit* conversion from raw pointer to `std::unique_ptr`.

Note that `std::shared_ptr` has `explicit` constructor for the very same reason.

Comment: How is this less risky: `void f(int *param) { std::unique_ptr<int> smart(param); }` or `void f(int *param) { delete param; }`?

Comment: @curiousguy: You obviously didn't understand my answer. `std::unique_ptr<int> smart(param);` is **explicit**, while my answer talks about the risk due to **implicit conversion** from `int*` to `std::unique_ptr<int>`.

Comment: You obviously didn't understand my comment. How is explicit less risky than implicit conversions?

Comment: @curiousguy: Know the meaning of "risky" first. then know the meaning of "explicit" and "implicit". Then you will understand my answer yourself.

Comment: So, you think I don't understand "risky"?

Comment: @curiousguy: Alright, then please teach me why the language allows you to make constructor `explicit` (if you want to). What is the advantage of making constructor `explicit`? Why the `explicit` keyword exists?

Comment: I will try. We do not want conversions (implicit or explicit) between unrelated concepts. For example, we do not want an implicit conversion from `float` to `string`, because they represent different concepts, with no *obvious and canonical* path between the two. A constructor has no name (which is a C++ design error IMO), and a one argument constructor was always an implicit conversion in the first C++ design, and this was soon recognised as an issue. The situation of C++ WRT explicit conversions is messy: a one-argument constructor creates an explicit conversion; this is not wanted.

Comment: (...) The usual example of one-argument constructor which conceptually does not represents a conversion is `array(int)`: an `int` is not "morally converted" (implicitly or explicitly), it is just a way to call the constructor. The fact that the constructor happens to have one argument should not make a difference here, but it does. C++ functional style cast is IMO one of the worst design error of C++ (with access control handling).

Comment: (...) With have to live with that, and an explicit constructor does not protect us as much as we would like: `static_cast<array>(1)` is still possible, we do not have non-converting constructors in C++ because **`array(1)` is a conversion** (a cast to type `array`).

Comment: @curiousguy: I will quote two statements from your comment which I didn't find clear enough. First you said, `(1)` *"We do not want conversions **(implicit or explicit)** between unrelated concepts."* (please note emphasized words). then you said, `(2)` *"For example, we do not want an **implicit** conversion from float to string, because they represent different concepts, ..."* . But does it mean that we don't want "explicit" conversion from `float` to `string` as well? If we want it, then why do we want "explicit" but not "implicit"? Doesn't it make your statetement `(1)` wrong?

Comment: I don't want to be able to write `string(1.)`. I don't want to read that in any C++ program, as I wouldn't know what the intent of the programmer was. OTOH, a specifically named function, like `to_string`, intended to convert its argument to its textual representation, is another issue. I don't view that `to_string` as a conversion function, and would rather name it `to_text`.

Comment: "_If we want it, then why do we want "explicit" but not "implicit"?_"  I don't want any user defined function to define an "explicit conversion" (a C style cast). But the C++ design implies that **a one argument constructor is actually an explicit conversion**. I don't like that, but I have to live with that. `static_cast<shared_ptr<T> >(p)` is unwanted (at least to me), at least as much as `shared_ptr<T> sp = p;` is unwanted. I just don't want to taking ownership as a particular explicit conversion.

Comment: **A conversion (implicit or explicit) should just convert, it should be pure** (not have side effects). `static_cast<U>(x);` should be side effect free. `static_cast<shared_ptr<T> >(p);` has a notable side effect: `delete p;` It means that **smart pointers are pathological objects**. To me the issue is not explicit vs. implicit, it is conversion constructor vs. ordinary constructor. Obviously, implicit conversions are more likely to be invoked accidentally than explicit conversions.

Comment: But a design error less likely to provoke programming errors than another design error is still a design error. ***Modelling as a conversion something which is not a conversion at all is a design error.** The construction of a `unique_ptr` from a raw pointer is not modelling a conversion. Some one argument constructors model a conversion: floating point to complex type, `const char*` to string type, `char` to string type (constructing a string with just one character). Here "complex" and "string" refer to some UDT with such constructors.

Comment: "_`std::unique_ptr<int> smart(param);` is explicit_" It is a direct initialization, not an explicit conversion and `std::unique_ptr<int> smart = param;` is not an implicit conversion attempt either. I don't think that `std::unique_ptr<int> smart(param);` is significantly less likely to hide programming errors than `std::unique_ptr<int> smart = param;`. **Both do not make very explicit that another `delete` call is implied** if `param` is an `int*`, but a previously implied `delete` call is delayed if `param` is a `std::unique_ptr<int>`.

Comment: @curiousguy: First, I'm finding your comments dogmatic, because all you're saying *"I don't want this; I don't like that"* without giving any rationale for your dislikes. Second, `to_string` *is* an **explicit conversion function** irrespective of what you think of it, and changing its name to `to_text` wouldn't change the fact that it is an "explicit" conversion function (start a topic if you want to know others opinion). Third, `std::unique_ptr<int> smart(param);` IS explicit conversion. ...[contd.]

Comment: ...[contd.]  Fourth, as you finally **admitted** : *"Obviously, implicit conversions are **more likely to be invoked accidentally** than explicit conversions."* Exactly, that is what I'm saying in my answer. Thank you. ;-)

Comment: "_Third, std::unique_ptr<int> smart(param); IS explicit conversion._" According to what? Who is "dogmatic" now?

Comment: @curiousguy: Why don't you read your own comment? ***"But the C++ design implies that a one argument constructor is actually an explicit conversion."*** So it is according to you too, *"std::unique_ptr<int> smart(param); IS explicit conversion"*. :-)

Comment: @curiousguy: Anyway, all I wanted to hear this from you : ***"Obviously, implicit conversions are more likely to be invoked accidentally than explicit conversions."*** So I think we should stop here.

Comment: "_Why don't you read your own comment? _" Why don't you read them? "_So it is according to you too, "`std::unique_ptr<int> smart(param);` IS explicit conversion". :-)_" No, I never wrote that. You could as well argue that `complex<double> c; c = 1.;` is an explicit conversion. (You could also argue that any implicit conversion is an explicit conversion.)

Comment: "_Second, `to_string` is an explicit conversion function irrespective of what you think of it,_" In your own dialect, perhaps. In C++, no.

Comment: @curiousguy: *"No, I never wrote that."*.  You did write ***"But the C++ design implies that a one argument constructor is actually an explicit conversion."*** (although it is not entirely correct; it is correct only if the constructor is declared with the keyword `explicit`, otherwise it is an implicit conversion function). And if `to_string()` is not a conversion function, then what it is? what does it *do* if it doesn't *convert* the argument to `string`?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15507/discussion-between-curiousguy-and-nawaz)

Comment: also with an explicit constructor one can write easily `void f(std::unique_ptr<int> param)
{}` the difference is on how you can call the function