# Iterate raw pointers from unique_ptr in map values

Tags: c++, c++11, smart-pointers

I am using unique_ptr in map values. I need to get those values as a list/vector of raw pointers. So far I have done as follows.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
#include <map>

class Foo {
  public:
    std::string val;

    Foo(std::string v) : val(v) {
    }
 };

 class Unique {
   public:
     std::map<int, std::unique_ptr<Foo>> unique_map;

     std::vector<Foo*> getFoos() {
       std::vector<Foo*> foos;
       for (auto& it : unique_map) {
         foos.push_back(it.second.get());
       }

       return foos;
     }
 };

 int main() {
   Unique unique;
   Foo* f1 = new Foo("1");
   Foo* f2 = new Foo("2");

   unique.unique_map.emplace(1, f1);
   unique.unique_map.emplace(2, f2);

   std::vector<Foo*> foos = unique.getFoos();

   for (Foo* foo : foos) {
     std::cout << foo->val;
   }

   std::cout<<"\n";

   return 0;
 }
```

But this fails to compile. The most relevent error message seems to be

> "/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_tree.h:140:49: note:   cannot convert
>   ‘std::forward((* & __args#1))’ (type ‘Foo*’) to type ‘const
>   std::unique_ptr&’"

But I am not sure I understand what it means since my understanding is that **it.second** returns a reference to the unique_ptr not the Foo instance it self assuming that's where the problem is. What needs to be done to fix this example?

**Edit**
I am using a somewhat older g++ version.

> g++ (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3) 4.8.4

with command line.

> g++ -std=c++11 -o unique unique.cpp

Comment: Compiles for me. `g++ (GCC) 6.1.1 20160602`, no extra flags.

Comment: Interesting. So it may be a compiler bug? Just added my compiler details.

Comment: Clang++ also accepts it (when given `-std=c++11`). `clang version 3.8.0 (tags/RELEASE_380/final`.

Comment: @chamibuddhika Its not a compiler bug. If it compiles, then that is a bug.

Comment: @Thomas Isn't the `unique_ptr` constructor explicit in the versions you tested the code with. Implicit conversion of raw pointers to  smart_pointer is a dangerous business

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you are getting is because implicit conversion of `Foo*` to `std::unique_ptr<Foo>` is not allowed. That is because, the constructor of `unique_ptr` taking a raw pointer is marked `explicit`.

```
explicit
      unique_ptr(pointer __p) noexcept
      : _M_t(__p, deleter_type())
      { static_assert(!is_pointer<deleter_type>::value,
                     "constructed with null function pointer deleter"); }
```

So, you should be creating a `unique_ptr` and `move` it while doing an `emplace`

NOTE: I am not sure why or how its working in g++ > 6.0 library. But personally I don't think its safe to convert raw pointers to smart pointer implicitly. To know why, see : https://stackoverflow.com/a/11367997/434233

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and the link. Makes more sense now. I am going to accept it as the better answer since you explained the reason for this behavior.

Comment: @Arunmu Totally agree that this implicit conversion is dangerous, but the Sutter article you link to talks about the other direction (smart to raw, not raw to smart).

Comment: @Thomas Yeah, thanks. Updated the link to point to relevant answer

Answer (score 1):

When I run this code, the complaint seems to be related to the creation of the `std::pair` class.

```
unique.unique_map.emplace(1, std::unique_ptr<Foo>(f1));
unique.unique_map.emplace(2, std::unique_ptr<Foo>(f2));
```

For me, this builds and it works, not that I can say for certain that it will really do what you desire. Just that it compiles and runs for me.

I spend most of my C++ time using QT libraries and classes, but, it looks to me like it is failing to find a way to turn a pair with a `FOO*` to the `unique_ptr<FOO>`.

Comment: Indeed! When I used the explicit std::pair based insertion it worked. Looks like emplace doesn't work the way I was thinking (at least for my current compiler it seems).