# Unique pointer error while object construction in C++

Tags: c++, unique-ptr

I am getting error while creating object as shown below using unique_ptr
Error: Error conversion from Account * to non-scalar type std::unique_ptr

```
std::unique_ptr <Account> acc_ptr = new Account(100);
```

If I use raw pointer as below, there is no error

```
Account *acc_ptr = new Account(100);
```

Why is it so?

Comment: related (/duplicate?) : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11367933/why-is-unique-ptrtt-explicit. If the first would compile then also `void foo(std::unique_ptr<int>){}  int x; foo(&x);` would compile and that would be bad.

Answer (score 6):

The [`std::unique_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/unique_ptr) constructor taking a pointer is `explicit`.

You need this:

```
std::unique_ptr <Account> acc_ptr(new Account(100));
```

Or, since C++14, use the better [`std::make_unique`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique) version:

```
auto acc_ptr = std::make_unique<Account>(100);
```