# Collection of template child classes

Tags: c++, templates, polymorphism, c++17

I'm still new to template classes. But I have a parent class and then a template child class.

```
namespace Foo::Bar {
    class BaseClass {
        // No declarations
    };

    template<typename ChildClassType>
    class ChildClass : public BaseClass {
        public:
            /// Public declarations
        private:
            // Private Members
    };
}
```

Edit: Including further information about the ChildClassType
So I have several structs that will use this template class.

```
struct foofoo {
// Declarations
}

struct barbar {
// Declarations
}
```

I want to be able to have a vector of multiple Child classes of each type so I used

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<BaseClass>> allChildTypeVector;
std::unique_ptr<ChildClass<foofoo>> childPtr;
allChildTypeVectors.push_back(childPtr);
```

Which is recommended by several other answers on here. But I am getting.

no instance of overloaded function "std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::push_back ....." matches the argument list

This same error is given if I do `allChildTypeVectors.push_back(new ChildClass<ChildClassType>);`

I know something is going wrong with my types but I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: what is `ChildClassType` ? or what is `ChildClass<ChildClassType>` ?Please post a [mcve]

Comment: Edited to include information about the ChildClassType @463035818_is_not_a_number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`std::unique_ptr`s cannot be copied. If you could copy them they would not be unique. Hence you get the error when you try to call `push_back`. If you do have a  `std::unique_ptr<ChildClass<foofoo>>` to be placed in the vector you can move it:

```
#include <string>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

class BaseClass {};

template<typename ChildClassType>
class ChildClass : public BaseClass {};   

struct foofoo {};
   
int main() {
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<BaseClass>> allChildTypeVector;
    std::unique_ptr<ChildClass<foofoo>> childPtr;
    allChildTypeVector.push_back(std::move(childPtr));
}
```

Note that this has nothing to do with `ChildClass` being a template. There are no template classes. `ChildClass` is a class template, and `ChildClass<foofoo>` is a class.

---

> So then why does allChildTypeVectors.push_back(new ChildClass); not work? Because that would be the ideal solution.

The constructor that takes a raw pointer is explicit. See here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/unique_ptr. You can call the constructor explicitly or use `std::make_unique`:

```
allChildTypeVector.push_back(std::unique_ptr<ChildClass<foofoo>>(new ChildClass<foofoo>));
allChildTypeVector.push_back(std::make_unique<ChildClass<foofoo>>());
```

A non-explicit constructor would be less than ideal because then raw pointers would implicitly convert to `unique_ptr`s unnoticed. For details I refer you to [Why is unique_ptr<T>(T*) explicit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11367933/why-is-unique-ptrtt-explicit).

Comment: So then why does `allChildTypeVectors.push_back(new ChildClass<foofoo>);` not work? Because that would be the ideal solution.

Comment: @Nbreen see udpate

Comment: Why not just use `emplace_back` instead? `allChildTypeVector.emplace_back(new ChildClass<foofoo>());` seems more straightforward than either of the alternatives.