# std::shared_ptr of this

Tags: c++, this, shared-ptr, this-pointer

I am currently trying to learn how to use smart pointers. However while doing some experiments I discovered the following situation for which I could not find a satifying solution:

Imagine you have an object of class A being parent of an object of class B (the child), but both should know each other:

```
class A;
class B;

class A
{
public:
    void addChild(std::shared_ptr<B> child)
    {
        children->push_back(child);

        // How to do pass the pointer correctly?
        // child->setParent(this);  // wrong
        //                  ^^^^
    }

private:        
    std::list<std::shared_ptr<B>> children;
};

class B
{
public:
    setParent(std::shared_ptr<A> parent)
    {
        this->parent = parent;
    };

private:
    std::shared_ptr<A> parent;
};
```

The question is how can an object of class A pass a `std::shared_ptr` of itself (`this`) to its child?

There are solutions for Boost shared pointers ([Getting a `boost::shared_ptr` for `this`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/142391/getting-a-boostshared-ptr-for-this)), but how to handle this using the `std::` smart pointers?

Comment: As is with any other tool you have to use it when it's appropriate. Using smart pointers for what you are doing is *not*

Comment: Similarly to boost. See [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this).

Comment: This is a problem at that level of abstraction.  You don't even know that "this" points to memory on the heap.

Comment: Well, the language doesn't, but _you_ do. As long as you keep track of what's where, you'll be fine.

Answer (score 216, accepted):

There is [`std::enable_shared_from_this`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this) just for this purpose. You inherit from it and you can call [`.shared_from_this()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this/shared_from_this) from inside the class. Also, you are creating circular dependencies here that can lead to resource leaks. That can be resolved with the use of [`std::weak_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/weak_ptr). So your code might look like this (assuming children rely on existence of parent and not the other way around):

```
class A;
class B;

class A
    : public std::enable_shared_from_this<A>
{
public:
    void addChild(std::shared_ptr<B> child)
    {
        children.push_back(child);

        // like this
        child->setParent(shared_from_this());  // ok
        //               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    }

private:     
    // note weak_ptr   
    std::list<std::weak_ptr<B>> children;
    //             ^^^^^^^^
};

class B
{
public:
    void setParent(std::shared_ptr<A> parent)
    {
        this->parent = parent;
    }

private:
    std::shared_ptr<A> parent;
};
```

Note however, that calling `.shared_from_this()` requires that `this` is owned by `std::shared_ptr` at the point of call. This means that you cannot create such object on stack anymore, and *generally* cannot call `.shared_from_this()` from within a constructor or destructor.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation and for pointing out my circular dependency problem.

Comment: Try to construct a `shared_ptr` based on a default-constructed `shared_ptr` and whatever you want to point it at...

Comment: @Deduplicator that's a, pardon my pun, rather pointless shared pointer. That constructor is intended to be used with pointers to members of the managed object or its bases. In any case what is your point (I'm sorry)? These non-owning `shared_ptr`s are are irrelevant to this question. `shared_from_this`'s preconditions clearly state that the object must be owned (not just pointed to) by some `shared_ptr` at the point of call.

Comment: @yurikilochek Could you please elaborate on why exactly it's impossible to call `.shared_from_this()` in constructor? Is it because the object is not yet created during constructor execution and non-determined value of `this` pointer?

Comment: @kazarey Ownership by a `shared_ptr`is required at the point of call, but in a typical usage pattern, i.e. something like `shared_ptr<Foo> p(new Foo());`, `shared_ptr` assumes ownership of the object only after it is fully constructed. It is possible to circumvent this by creating `shared_ptr` in constructor initialized with `this` and storing it somewhere  non-local (e.g. in a reference argument) so it doesn't die when constructor completes. But this convoluted scenario is unlikely to be necessary.

Comment: given that the Parent normally should have the ownership of Children, isn't it confusing to declare a weak_ptr of children in the parent class, while the children hold the ownership(shared_ptr) of the parent? so who own the children now?

Comment: What's holding the tree together when the reference to the children are only weak pointers and only the root node is held directly?

Comment: @JimmyR.T. something else. Think of it as a set of stacks that share common prefix rather than a tree per se.

Comment: Gave a upcount on this response for answering the OPs question. Those who don't but suggest the "better way" are often mistaken. 

Also did an upcount because I needed this answer for a problem. An idiom I've used multiple times is putting "this" in a container to obtain a complete list of all  class instances, i.e. to walk the container to process every instance. Please don't exert yourself explaining why this is problematic. I know the problems and how to avoid them.

Answer (score 13):

You have several problems in you design, that seem to stem from you misunderstanding of smart pointers.

Smart pointers are used to declare ownership. You are breaking this by declaring that both the parents owns all children, but also that each child own it's parent. Both can't be true.

Also, you are returning a weak pointer in `getChild()`. By doing so, you are declaring that the caller shouldn't care about the ownership. Now this can be very limiting, but also by doing so, you must make sure that the child in question won't get destroyed while any weak pointers are still held, if you would use a smart pointer, it would get sorted out by itself.

And the final thing. Usually, when you are accepting new entities, you should usually accept raw pointers. Smart pointer can have their own meaning for swapping children between parents, but for general usage, you should accept raw pointers.

Comment: Hello, I know this is old, sorry. You say that children shouldn't own their parents (while the parents own the children) because obviously that is a circular dependency. But what if a child item needs to know its parent? Should it store a weak pointer to the parent? A raw pointer? Or is there something wrong about the very idea? The reason I ask is that Qt QAbstractItemModel requires a child to know which index it is of the parent's children. It ends up in child->parent->children.indexOf(child) type calls, probably bad design, but it is what it is!

Comment: @Dan Depending on the local style guides. I would generally use a raw pointer to represent a non-owning reference. We also might get something standard at some point: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/observer_ptr

Comment: Many thanks! That is what I have ended up choosing in the end (a raw pointer). That is good to know about the observer_ptr - I'm constantly impressed with the direction modern c++ is heading.