# How to fix `terminate called without an active exception` when calling join

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads

I've written a simple implementation of thread pool and I get `terminate called without an active exception` error. I've checked if threads are joinable then I tried to debug where destructors are called but to no success.

`workerpool.hpp`

```cpp
#ifndef WORKERPOOL_H
#define WORKERPOOL_H

#include <condition_variable>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <mutex>
#include <optional>
#include <queue>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>

class task {
  public:
    virtual void operator()() = 0;
    virtual ~task() = default;
};

class WorkerPool {
  private:
    class Worker {
      private:
        std::shared_ptr<WorkerPool> wp;
        long id;

      public:
        Worker(std::shared_ptr<WorkerPool> _wp, long _id) : wp(_wp), id(_id) {
            std::cout << "Worker " << id << " created" << std::endl;
        };
        ~Worker() { std::cout << "Worker " << id << " destroyed" << std::endl; }

        void operator()() {
            while (!wp->stop) {
                auto t = wp->fetch_task();
                if (!t.has_value())
                    continue;
                else
                    t.value()->operator()();
            }
            std::cout << "thread " << id << " ended" << std::endl;
        };
    };

    std::vector<std::thread> workers;

    std::queue<std::unique_ptr<task>> q;
    std::condition_variable cv;
    std::mutex mx;

    std::optional<std::unique_ptr<task>> fetch_task() {
        std::unique_lock l(mx);
        cv.wait(l, [&] { return !q.empty() || stop; });
        if (stop)
            return {};
        auto res = std::move(q.front());
        q.pop();
        return std::move(res);
    };

  public:
    WorkerPool() {
        std::cout << "worker pool created" << std::endl;
        for (long i = 0; i < std::thread::hardware_concurrency(); i++) {
            workers.push_back(
                std::thread(Worker(std::shared_ptr<WorkerPool>(this), i)));
        }
    }

    ~WorkerPool() {
        std::cout << "worker pool destroyed" << std::endl;
        terminate();
        for (size_t i = 0; i < workers.capacity(); i++) {
            if (workers[i].joinable())
                workers[i].join();
        }
    }

    WorkerPool(WorkerPool const &) = delete;
    WorkerPool &operator=(WorkerPool const &) = delete;
    WorkerPool(WorkerPool &&) = delete;
    WorkerPool &operator=(WorkerPool &&) = delete;

    bool stop;

    void submit(std::unique_ptr<task> t) {
        std::lock_guard l(mx);
        q.push(std::move(t));
        cv.notify_one();
    }

    void terminate() {
        stop = true;
        cv.notify_all();
    }
};

#endif // WORKERPOOL_H
```

`main.cpp`

```cpp
#include <workerpool.hpp>

#include <condition_variable>
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>

using namespace std;

class foo : public task {
public:
    void operator()() override { cout << "test" << endl; }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    WorkerPool wp;

    wp.submit(make_unique<foo>());

    wp.terminate();

    cout << "program ended" << endl;
    return 0; 
}
```

Console output:

```
> make run
rm -f bin/*
clang++ -std=c++17 -fuse-ld=lld  -pthread -Iinclude -Llib -O2 src/main.cpp -o bin/main 
./bin/main
worker pool created
Worker 0 created
Worker 0 destroyed
Worker 0 destroyed
Worker 1 created
Worker 1 destroyed
Worker 1 destroyed
Worker 2 created
Worker 2 destroyed
Worker 2 destroyed
Worker 3 created
Worker 3 destroyed
Worker 3 destroyed
thread 0 ended
Worker 0 destroyed
worker pool destroyed
program endedthread 2 ended
Worker 2 destroyed
worker pool destroyed

worker pool destroyed
terminate called without an active exception
make: *** [Makefile:32: run] Aborted (core dumped)
```

Comment: As far as I can tell the program  only creates 1  `WorkerPool ` but 2 are destroyed (2 * _"worker pool destroyed"_).  Put a breakpoint in the body of the destructor and inspect the call stack to see if you can find out why.

Comment: `std::thread(Worker(std::shared_ptr<WorkerPool>(this), i)));` is creating multiple unrelated `shared_ptr` to the same instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
std::shared_ptr<WorkerPool>(this)
```

You can't just do that. You're telling the `shared_ptr` that it owns the object, but it doesn't. Its lifetime is already being managed elsewhere (in this case, "on the stack" in `main`).

Consequently you have apparently ended up with a double delete (notice 2 × *"worker pool destroyed"*). Formally, the results are undefined, particularly as you create yet more unrelated `shared_ptr`s for *each* worker thread: if the program hadn't crashed, I wager you'd've seen 4 × that line.

There are ways to make this possible, [using `enable_shared_from_this`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11711094/560648), though [that cannot work in the constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this/shared_from_this) (because the "original" `shared_ptr` won't have finished taking ownership yet).

Comment: Note that the `shared_ptr` to `this` is needed in the constructor. `enable_shared_from_this` doesn't work in that context.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux True.