# Pass an object with this to another object

Tags: c++, c++14, shared-ptr

If I have a `Y` which has a member pointer to `X`, how can I make an instance of `Y` in `X`?

I thought about passing it somewhat like this:

```
#include <memory>

struct X;
struct Y 
{    
    Y(int n, std::shared_ptr<X> x) 
        : n_(n)
        , x_(x)
    {}

    std::shared_ptr<X> x_;
    int n_;
};
    
struct X 
{
    void d()
    {
        auto y = std::make_shared<Y>(20, this);
    } 
};
    
int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Also, out of concern caused by the wording of the question: If you are under the impression that `shared_ptr<>` is the "default" pointer to use, you are very mistaken.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [std::shared\_ptr of this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11711034/stdshared-ptr-of-this)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possible solution using `std::enable_shared_from_this`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

struct X;

struct Y 
{    
    Y(int n, std::shared_ptr<X> x):
    n_(n),
    x_(x)
    {
        
    }
    std::shared_ptr<X> x_;
    int n_;
};

struct X : std::enable_shared_from_this<X>
{
    void d()
    {
        auto y = make_shared<Y>(20, this->shared_from_this());
    }
    
};

int main()
{
    auto x = make_shared<X>();
    x->d();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `shared_from_this`. [Here you can find an example.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11711034/stdshared-ptr-of-this) This solution did not always work for me though so you have to try it out for your self. If it does not work use a raw pointer or a reference.

Comment: It is not optimal so I'd suggest using shared_from_this, in case shared_from_this does not work I would suggest just using a raw pointer.