Why does this std::weak_ptr apparently prevent freeing memory, and how can I detect this bug?
In my C++ code I have a std::shared_ptr that goes out of scope, which reduces its use count to 0, so the pointed-to object is destroyed. This works fine. However, if I have a std::weak_ptr that points to that std::shared_ptr and stays alive, the pointed-to memory apparently is not actually freed.
Example:
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

int main() {
    int* my_raw_ptr = nullptr;
    std::weak_ptr<int> my_wp;
    {
        auto my_sp = std::make_shared<int>(42);
        std::cout << "my_sp value: " << *my_sp << std::endl;
        my_raw_ptr = &(*my_sp);

        my_wp = my_sp;  // (1)
    }

    std::cout << "my_raw_ptr value: " << *my_raw_ptr << std::endl;

    return 0;
}

(on Godbolt: https://godbolt.org/z/Kd46fn8zc)
Now, I understand that this code has undefined behaviour (namely, in dereferencing my_raw_ptr after my_sp has gone out of scope). However, my concern is that this error is not caught by any of the tools I tried:

when compiling with clang 19.1.0 with -O0 -fsanitize=address -fno-omit-frame-pointer, the program does not show any error at runtime.
Valgrind 3.22.0 does not show any runtime error.
running the program with jemalloc and "memory junking" (i.e. with MALLOC_CONF=junk:true LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjemalloc.so.2) does not cause any wrong behaviour at runtime. I would expect that the junk:true option causes the freed memory to be filled with junk data, making the bug easily visible.

Even more strange: if I remove the std::weak_ptr assignment from the code (i.e. disable the line marked with (1)), all of the three tools correctly detect the bug!
Question: what can I do to make this bug detectable by runtime analysis tools? And, out of curiosity: why does the std::weak_ptr prevent the detection of the bug so well?

Using std::make_shared means that the control block and data block are in the same memory allocation (avoiding 2 allocations).  The use of std::weak_ptr means that the control block (and therefore the control+data block) cannot be freed.  The data object will have been destroyed by placement delete, but for int this is a no-op.

Since you assign the shared_ptr to the a weak_ptr, the memory is not freed when the shared_ptr goes out of scope. Therefor the bug cannot be found. This is discussed in this post. As you mention, the bug is detected as soon as you do NOT assign the shared_ptr to the weak_ptr, since the memory is freed when the shared_ptr goes out of scope.

Given your other comments, it seems like the bug was the raw pointer this was passed to a third party function that held a direct reference to the raw pointer after that third-party function call ended . The whole deferred lambda mechanism is in error and needs to ensure it holds strong references. enable_shared_from_this may be of use. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11711034/stdshared-ptr-of-this

Don't mix raw pointers and smart pointers.

First, you must understand how std::make_shared works.
When you use it, it allocates memory larger than your object. This extra space contains information needed to handle reference counting and the destruction process.
Now, both shared_ptr and weak_ptr keep the entire block of memory alive. When all shared_ptrs instances reach the end of their lifetimes, the destructor of the pointed-to object is invoked, but the memory remains unchanged because reference counting is still required to manage weak_ptrs.
In this case, the object is destroyed, but the memory still exists. An int is a special case since it has a trivial destructor, so you can access this memory without invoking undefined behavior (UB). However, if the pointed-to type has a non-trivial destructor, accessing this memory would cause undefined behavior.
If you do not use std::make_shared, you will have two blocks of memory (one for reference counting and one for the actual object). When all shared_ptr instances end their lifetimes, the block of memory holding the actual object will be freed. Live demo shows the address sanitizer detecting a memory issue.

Thanks for the explanation! I've replaced std::make_shared() by std::shared_ptr<...>{new ...}, and then the bug is indeed detected. But I do want to use std::make_shared() in my code. So... is there some "debug flag" or so to make ~std::shared_ptr() zero out the memory, to catch such bugs more easily?

@oliver code review the use of raw pointers pointing to memory managed by owning pointers - this should be a red flag.

@RichardCritten The bug came up in my code because an object method was called on the weak_ptr, but then that object method passed its this pointer to a lambda that was executed in a deferred manner on another thread. I will try to catch such cases by code review, but my impression is that there were no "obvious" red flags; only the combination of these actions caused the bug.

Is the bug detected by your tools if the pointed-to object have a non-trivial destructor?

@MarekR "An int is a special case since it has a trivial destructor, so you can access this memory without invoking undefined behavior (UB)" - accessing the memory of any destroyed object, even a trivial one, is still UB.

@oliver: you can make the destructor for the object explicitly set the memory to some invalid/detectable state that will make it easier to see accesses to destroyed objects in a debugger.
