# Getting shared_ptr for "this" object to another function : giving run time exception

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, smart-pointers

Actually I want to extract shared_ptr from 'this' object in an another function.
For the same suppose we have a situation where a "Thing member function" needs to pass a pointer to "this" object to another function like:

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#include<memory>

using namespace std;


class Thing {
public:
 void foo();
 void defrangulate();
};
void Thing::defrangulate()
{
}

void transformIt(shared_ptr<Thing> ptr)
{
 ptr->defrangulate();
 /* etc. */
}

void Thing::foo()
{
 // we need to transformIt this object
 shared_ptr<Thing> sp_for_this(this);
 transformIt(sp_for_this);
}

int main()
{
 shared_ptr<Thing> t1(new Thing);// start a manager object for the Thing
 t1->foo();
}
```

output:
Debug Assertion failed!
Expression: _BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID(pHead->nBlockUse)

Am I doing any mistake which causing this run time exception ?

Comment: That error message suggests memory corruption to me.  I do not see anything obviously wrong with your code and would suggest `valgrind`.

Comment: This is why I prefer using raw pointers over shared_ptr for function parameters. http://stackoverflow.com/a/142945/5987

Answer (score 4):

You are causing a double-delete.  That's because when you create a shared_ptr from this, you don't tell it that the raw pointer is already owned by someone else.  You need to either use a custom, no-op deleter (construct shared_ptr with `(this, [](void*){})`, or use [`std::enable_shared_from_this`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this).