# use *this as std::shared_ptr

Tags: c++, class, signals, shared-ptr

here is a "chess++" problem that I'm facing wright now with my nested class,
although it may look like some joke, it's not a joke but real problem which I want to either solve or change the way to achieve the same thing in my project.

```
#include <map>
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>
#include <sigc++/signal.h>

class foo
{
public:
    struct bar;

    typedef sigc::signal<void, std::shared_ptr<bar>> a_signal;

    struct bar
    {
        bar()
        {
            some_signal.connect(sigc::mem_fun(*this, &foo::bar::func));
        }

        void notify()
        {
            some_signal.emit(this); // how to ??
        }

        void func(std::shared_ptr<foo::bar> ptr)
        {
            std::cout << "you haxor!" << std::endl;
            // use the pointer ptr->
        }

        a_signal some_signal;
    };

    std::map<int, std::shared_ptr<bar>> a_map;
};

int main()
{
    std::shared_ptr<foo::bar> a_foo_bar;
    foo foo_instance;

    foo_instance.a_map.insert(std::pair<int, std::shared_ptr<foo::bar>>(4, a_foo_bar));
    foo_instance.a_map.at(0)->notify();
    return 0;
}
```

What I want to do here is to emit a signal.
the signal is declared as one that triggers a handler that takes a shared_ptr as an argument.
the function notify() should convert *this into shared_ptr, how do I do that to make the above code run?

Comment: std::shared_from_this

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting a boost::shared\_ptr for this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/142391/getting-a-boostshared-ptr-for-this)

Comment: [Reference for said function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this/shared_from_this) (note your class has to inherit from the appropriate class)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Derive from `enable_shared_from_this`:

```
struct bar : std::enable_shared_from_this<bar>
```

to get a member `shared_from_this()`:

```
some_signal.emit(shared_from_this());
```

As long as the current object is owned by at least one shared pointer, this will return a shared pointer, sharing ownership with that pointer. Note that, in your program, `a_foo_bar` is empty, so neither this nor the call to `notify` will work. Also beware that it won't work from the constructor or destructor, since the object is not owned by a shared pointer at that time.

Comment: Note that if the current object is *not* owned by a `shared_ptr`, `shared_from_this()` will *throw*. So it would probably be a good idea to hide `bar`'s constructor and instead expose a static factory method that returns `std::shared_ptr<bar>` so you can guarantee that all instances will be in `shared_ptr`s.

Comment: @dlf: Worse than that: if it's not owned by a shared pointer, then you get undefined behaviour. (The example implementation given in the standard, storing a weak pointer, would throw `bad_weak_ptr`, but there's no requirement to use that implementation).